# How does the DBMS affect application performance? And Informix GUI tools?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, informix

I use [Informix](http://www.informix.com/) DBMS in all my web applications. My question has two parts:

1. Does the DBMS have a big effect on the performance of my applications
   and if the answer is yes what about Informix and `MS SQL Server in this
   issue?
2. I want some GUI tools to facilitate my job when writing queries,
   creating database, relationships, ERD, etc.  The Informix client
   is so bad. There are no facilities at all. I want some tools
   like `SQL Server Management Studio`

Answer (score 3):

As a GUI tool for Informix you can use Aqua Data Studio from Aquafold.  It also supports MS SQL Server.

As of the performance: it depends.  How well is your Database design.  Do you use indexes, is your query well-written, etc. etc.  Very hard to answer your question, we just don't know enough.

Comment: Yes, aqua data it works well with ms-sql, but it doesn't have visual query analysis support for informix. It also costs around 500$ for single developer

Answer (score 1):

Aqua Data Studio is good but quite expensive. An open source tool [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net/downloads.html) is also an effective tool for informix.
Informix have its own charm but i guess it should not be said that MS-Sql Server is slower or not good in performance. You may decide DBMS according to your nature of application. There are many techniques to optimize Database performance like, Applying Indexes/ Not too many Joins/ Queries can be optimize too/ Stored Procedure can also be used/ Multi-DBs level etc.

Once i need to develop Social Media site, i used MySQL in this project but only for POSTs i installed MongoDB.

Regards,

Salik

Answer (score 1):

To design a solution that would perform the best, one needs to know the nature of the application you are building. For example, if you are building a system that needs to process and compute large volume of data and computations can be distributed, a "traditional" relational database is not a good option no matter what vendor you choose. You would be better off with an option that supports [sharding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29), [Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) and will likely be based on some kind of [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) solution.

If you are sticking with RDMS and building something that has a lot of reads and not a lot of writes, go for a database that supports [Snapshot Isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation) which will allow your readers to not be blocked by writers.

Cost also plays into this - some RDMS systems are free, some are not. Your question is way to general to be answered specifically.